Absence of .env files on ec2 is failing the nestjs server to run on EC2 instance
I'm creating a NestJs Application and I've 2 env files, named
.local.env & .development.env
In local setting the variable from npm run start:dev and the start:dev looks like this "start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch",
Now while importing the file i'm using the below snippet to load the specific file in local,
import { ApolloDriver, ApolloDriverConfig } from "@nestjs/apollo";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { GraphQLModule } from "@nestjs/graphql";
import { CONSTANTS } from "../../../CONSTANTS";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { databaseProviders } from "src/typeorm.config";
import { moduleIndex } from "./modules.index";
import { User } from "../graphQL/Users/users.entity";

let region: string = CONSTANTS.DEVELOPMENT_REGION;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() === CONSTANTS.DEVELOPMENT_REGION) {
    region = "development"
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() === CONSTANTS.DEVELOPMENT_LOCAL_REGION) {
    region = "local"
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() === CONSTANTS.DEVELOPMENT_STAGE_REGION) {
    region = "stage"
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase() === CONSTANTS.DEVELOPMENT_PROD_REGION) {
    region = "prod"
}
console.log("Region: ", region);
const importsArray = [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
        driver: ApolloDriver,
        autoSchemaFile: CONSTANTS.SCHEMA_FILE_PATH
    }),
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
        envFilePath: `.${region}.env`,
        isGlobal: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(databaseProviders),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])
]

const expArray = [...importsArray, ...moduleIndex];

export default expArray;

This configuration works prettymuch well in local, but when I build the project in Amazon Linux and run it using pm2 it's not reading the NODE_ENV variable, neither the file itself.
I'm using ConfigService for reading env variables. like below,
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {
  static service: ConfigService;

  constructor(service: ConfigService) {
    AppConfig.service = service;
  }

  static get(key: string): any {
    return AppConfig.service.get(key);
  }
}

Use,
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
and using it like AppConfig.get('JWT_SECRET').
Can anyone please suggest me how can I handle .env issue on ec2.
Thanks in advance.

Normally .env files would be named .env.local, .env.development, and .env.production not the other way round.
